# Where to find ads of a certain size to place on my web site?

Tags: marketing, advertising

Where can I find ads to place on my site that are `125px x 125px` to place one my site? The sites content is mixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Google AdPlanner](https://www.google.com/adplanner/) to advertise slots you have available on your website. These advertised slots will appear for people on AdSense (mostly) and you can tell the AdPlanner to use any ad agencies you will find in the future to rotate the ads displayed in the slots.

It is not really finding you ads, if there is no one who is creating such ads ... but AdSense might auto-create text ads in that format in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

BuySellAds.com will probably earn you more than using google.  i would also look into affiliate programs such as commission junction and linkshare.

what kind of site is it?